# Event $emitted from controller $scope not always reaching listener defined in $rootScope

Tags: angularjs

In our app, there are several async calls to the backend that might take some time, and we use an "hourglass" indicator to show that the app is busy (in those cases where the user isn't allowed to poke the UI while the call isn't being processed). This is done by emitting events from the active controller that makes the backend calls to `$rootScope` which listens for those events and raises or clears a flag controlling the showing of the progress indicator.

I've done a simplified version of this in JSFiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/e3vZY/

Now, in one particular case, when the same chain of actions is done in the app two times in a row, on the second time the indicator is stuck on the screen indefinitely, blocking all user actions. On the first time it works just as intended, like in many other places where the same approach always seems to work.

It seems that on those troublesome occasions the event is emitted successfully - a conclusion which I've reached by placing a local listener in the same `$scope` as where the event is emitted from (in the fiddle, there's a console logging call to show this) - but it never reaches the listener in `$rootScope`. In the actual implementation there are no listeners for the event elsewhere, so our code doesn't explicitly end the propagation on any level.

The chain of actions I'm talking about includes several calls to the backend, showing and hiding the indicator several times, switching tabs in an `ng-view` etc. Unfortunately *I can't reproduce the problem it in the fiddle, so this question is more of the theoretical kind...*

**What could cause the event not to be propagated to `$rootScope`?**

Since the problem only occurs on the second time the exact same actions are taken and works perfectly on the first, I'd imagine it could related to timing issues or something.

**Edit:**

I tried putting the `$emit` call inside a `$timeout` (without delay) in case that would affect the timing but the behavior stays exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you've managed to fix the problem when you simplified the code in the jsFiddle, so there is probably an error somewhere in the code you're not showing us. It's probably not an error in Angular. If you look at the source of `$emit()` in angular.js, there's nothing to indicate that it could miss calling a listener that's attached to the root scope.

Perhaps you could add some debugging code inside `$emit()` in angular.js to get more details on what is happening?

**EDIT**

The error is explained in the comments.

Comment: Is it possible that your scope is being destroyed at the same time or before you're trying to emit the event? Can you change so that you emit the event on `$rootScope` instead of your local scope?

Comment: (I removed my previous comment, as I noticed an error in my debug code.) I added some debug logging to the `$emit` implementation, and it seems to travel up scopes to `$rootScope` but the listener there just won't fire. And now, with the logging in the code, the problem occurs also on the first try...

Comment: Have you tried emitting the event directly to `$rootScope` instead of on the scope you have?

Comment: No, I could try doing that and see if something changes. I added some logging to the Angular code and it now seems like the `$emit` can't find the listener in `$rootScope` when it's looping through the scopes... Weird.

Comment: I now tried emitting the event directly to `$rootScope` and that does seem to work. Also, your question about my scope being destroyed (or somehow modified) might be related to the problem, as right after the `$emit` there is a view change happening with `$location.path(...)`. (Don't know if it can mess things up.)

Comment: Yup, that might be the cause as the location change will remove your controller, and start to destroy the current scope. And if you emit an event on a destroyed scope that won't bubble up. If you look at the source for `scope.$destroy()` you'll see that `scope.$parent` is set to null, which means that when you later `$emit()` an event, it cannot pass it upwards to the parent, as the parent is removed.

Comment: Then that's probably the problem. I guess one of the scopes in the `$emit` processing loop has its parent set to null during the loop, and thus the propagation ends before reaching `$rootScope`.

Comment: It shouldn't be happening in that loop as the loop is synchronous. Try adding `$scope.$on('$destroy', function() { console.log('destroyed') });` in your controller, and a `console.log('emit')` when you emit the event. You'll probably see that the scope has been destroyed before your event is emitted.

Comment: I tried that as well, and what happens is pretty much like you said - when the problem occurs, the `$destroy` logging comes first, then the local listener launches. However, my logging in the Angular code seems to suggest that the loop goes through 2 scopes, i.e. it finds a parent once after triggering the listener in the current scope (but that doesn't have a listener or a parent, so nothing happens anymore). Anyway, the problem is definitely in changing the view, whatever the details. (Btw, thanks for editing the answer. Tried it myself but the change was rejected immediately...)